# Vertex paint colours keep flickering

Tags: texture-baking, baking, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

A **Blender** beginner here.
So I recently modeled a low poly plane and applied some vertex paint to it, but after I baked the vertex paint to an id colour map the vertex paint started flickering like so 
[image]

And here is my id map. I think there no issue with it. 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You probably have faces of different colors sharing the same space, flickering will result from these faces conflicting with each othe during the drawing of the model.

Check the flickering spots in Edit Mode, make sure to show occluded geometry (untick the button marked in red). Delete any faces that should not be there.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Also commonly known as z-fighting.